# список как набор аргументов

Tags: tcl

есть функция:

```
% proc test {args} {llength $args}
```

если передать ей два аргумента, то она ожидаемо вернёт число два (количество аргументов):

```
% test x y
2
```

и если передать ей список из двух компонентов, то, в принципе, ожидаемо, будет возвращена единица:

```
% test [list x y]
1
```

понятно, что внутри собственной функции я такую ситуацию могу обработать и «залезть» внутрь списка, но нельзя ли обойтись без изменения функции и каким-то образом преобразовать имеющийся список в набор аргументов?

---

вот менее абстрактный пример: библиотечная функция `file`. есть команда `file split путь`, «разбирающая» переданный путь на отдельные компоненты, и возвращающая их в виде списка:

```
% file split /x/y
/ x y
```

и есть «противоположная» ей команда `file join компоненты`, «собирающая» путь из переданных ей компонентов. она отлично работает, если компоненты указать отдельными аргументами:

```
% file join / x y
/x/y
```

но не работает, если ей передать список, например, возвращаемый командой `file split путь`:

```
% file join [file split /x/y]
/ x y
```

как же всё-таки преобразовать список в набор аргументов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно воспользоваться специальной синтаксической конструкцией `{*}` — [argument expansion](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/293.md):

```
% test {*}[list x y]
2
% file join {*}[file split /x/y]
/x/y
```

она должна быть написана слитно с аргументом-списком, без пробелов.

---

как написано в tip-е (tcl improvement proposal) по приведённой ссылке, эта конструкция введена в версии tcl 8.5. в более ранних версиях, видимо, [надо использовать `eval`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/%7B%2A%7D).